# How to skip duplicate in scrapy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, duplicates

I am new to Scrapy. I wrote this script :

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
        #identity
        name="mysite"

        #Request
        def start_requests(self):
            url= 'example.com/doc/file/vid'

            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

        #Response
        def parse(self, response):
            loader = ItemLoader(item=VideoInfoItem(), response=response)

            for info in response.selector.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'thumb-list__item')]"):
                loader= ItemLoader(item=InfoItem(), selector=info, response=response)
                loader.add_xpath('text', ".//div[@class='info']/a")
                loader.add_xpath('url', ".//div[@class='info']/a/@href")
                url = video.xpath(".//a[@class='image-container], callback=self.parse_video)
```

When I run the script again I want to skip duplicates before the #Response.
I try a few things but did not work.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you are starting the script the second time from the same start URL and want to skip all the sides you've visitied in the first run? So you just want to continue were you left?

Comment: Yes exactly what I mean

Comment: I want to skip all the post on the site that I already visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue crawling from the point where you stopped in a previous run, you have to make sure all required information is persisted after a run. As the [scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html#jobs-pausing-and-resuming-crawls) states:

> To enable persistence support you just need to define a job directory through the JOBDIR setting.

You can either add this setting via a `settings.py` file:

```
JOBDIR = 'crawls/somespider-1'
```

or by starting your spider with the following command:

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

You should prefer the first option as it allows you to easily add more settings to your spider.

Comment: I don't see any #JOBDIR in settings.py. I don't really understand. Any examples?

Comment: See my updated answer. If you don't see the parameter in the settings.py simply add it.